# undefined control sequence with \addplot

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to include a graph for an assignment with the following tikz code

packages:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
```

tikz code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    declare function={
        func(\x) = (\x < 1\4) * (0) +
        and(\x >= 1/3,  \x <= 1/4) * (sin(pi/(\x))) + 
        (\x > 1/3) * (0)
    ;
    }
]
\begin{axis}[
    axis z line=middle, axis y line=middle,
    ymin=-3, ymax=3, ytick ={-3,...,3}, ylabel=$y$,
    xmin=-2, xmax=2, xtick ={-2,...,2}, xlabel=$x$,
domain=-2:2,samples=101,
]

\addplot [black,thick] {func(\x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

the syntax was mostly copied from another post, I just changed some variables and the function. when I  try to compile (is that the right word?) it gives me the following error message "! undefined control sequence" (it points to \addplot as the culprit).

also I'm supposed to plot this graph with bounds in terms of a general n, I chose 1/3 and 1/4 to represent it but I'd like the x values labelled 1/n and 1/n+1 on the graph if possible. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! If I add a preamble, your code compiles *if* I change the definition of the function. I do not understand your definition. Isn't `(\x < 1\4) * (0) ` *always 0, and likewise `(\x > 1/3) * (0)`. And how many `x` are both `>=1/3` and `<=1/4`? If you tell us what function you're after, you'll get a full answer. (Notice also that the arguments of trigonometric functions are supposed to be in degrees, so I am wondering if you really want to plot `sin(pi/(\x))` rather than `sin(180/(\x))`, say.)

Comment: the sequence of functions in question is defined piecewise as follows
f_n(x) = sin(pi/x) for all x in [1/(n+1),1/n] and 0 everywhere else.
thanks for the heads up with degrees as opposed to radians I'll try that now. Which preamble was it that you added?
The question then asks that we "sketch the graph of f_n" which I've interpreted as graphing it for some general integer n (even this doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me because the shape of the graph seems to depend on the congruence class of n mod 2).

Comment: I added an answer that precisely plots this function for `n=3`. It has the preamble as well as a simple trick to deal with the pole. I do not know anything about your question but do not see why this would only depend on whether `n` is even or odd, which is your `mod 2` thing.

Comment: I just figured that it would alternate between the intervals of sin [0, pi] and [pi, 2pi]
of course I forgot that it's sin^2 not sin so that point's moot now anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE! After clarification in the comments, I now plot a series of functions `(sin(180/(\x)))^2` in the intervals `[1/(n+1),1/n]`. I hope that you find the syntax self-explanatory, and that this allows you to plot what you want.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
    declare function={func(\n,\x) = 
    ifthenelse(\x>=1/(\n+1),ifthenelse( \x <=
    1/\n,(sin(180/(\x)))^2,0),0);
    }
]
\begin{axis}[
    axis z line=middle, axis y line=middle,
    ymin=-3, ymax=3, ytick ={-3,...,3}, ylabel=$y$,
    xmin=-2, xmax=2, xtick ={-2,...,2}, xlabel=$x$,
domain=0.1:1,samples=12*3*4*5+1,
]
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,...,6}
{\addplot [black,thick] {func(#1,x)};}
\draw[thick] (-2,0) -- (2,0);
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks this is almost exactly what I wanted to graph.
Unfortunately I realised that I meant to graph sin^2(pi/x) which shouldn't be too difficult to amend. This graph doesn't seem quite right though. 
if x is between 1/n+1 and 1/n for an integer n then x = 1/(n + 1/2) should yield 1 (sin^2((n+1)pi) = 1).
I've probably made a stupid error somewhere, I'm just not sure where.
Thanks for all the help

Comment: @MarvinGaTeX I hope to improved now and just defined a function for arbitrary `n`. Notice that setting the samples appropriate seems also to be important. By appropriate I mean that there is one sample at `x=1/n`, one at `1/(n+1)` and some in between.

Comment: Thank you very much!
I may fiddle with this to print out just a single value of n but this was exactly what I was after. Sorry for the poorly phrased question and omission.